# Segmentation fault in C using GCC compiler while performing quicksort

Tags: c, gcc, fedora, quicksort, c99

I have written the following C99 code to perform a quicksort on a fixed array. However, after printing the initial array, it is giving a segmentation fault. I do not have any debugger right now, I am using KWrite and then terminal to compite and run. Here is the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define LEN 8

int arr[8] = {3,5,7,1,2,4,6,8};

void printarr()
{
    printf("\n");
    for (int i = 0; i<LEN; i++)
        printf("\t %d", arr[i]);
    printf("\n");
}


void quicksort(int _left,int _right)
{
    int left = _left;
    int right = _right;
    int pivot = (left+right)/2;

    while (left<=right)
    {
        while(pivot>arr[left])
            left--;
        while (pivot<arr[right])
            right++;
        if(left<=right)
        {
            int temp = arr[right];
            arr[right] = arr[left];
            arr[left] = arr[temp];
            left++;
            right--;
        }
    }

    if (_left<right)
        quicksort(_left, right);
    else
        quicksort(left, _right);
}

int main()
{
    int left = 0, right = LEN-1;

    printf("Unsorted array:");
    printarr();

    quicksort(left,right);

    printf("Sorted array:");
    printarr();
}
```

Please have a look and let me know which part of the code is causing this issue.

Comment: Well, for one, you're comparing `pivot`, an *index* calculated between `left` and `right` (also indexes), with *values* from the array (`arr[left]` and `arr[right]`). Or was that too obvious? This needs the business-end of a debugger.

Comment: You should already have gdb installed, use it. BTW KWrite is not a programmer's editor, it's a word processor. You are better off using Kate.

Comment: KWrite and Kate use the same text editor engine, it is also used in KDevelop, Kate does have better handling for things like multiple files in a project and builtin code completeion than KWrite however. KWord, or Calligra Words today, is more of a word processor.

Comment: Step one in debugging: use as simple a test case as possible. Start with sorting a one-element list. It's simple enough that you can go through the code by hand without compiling it.

Answer (score 3):

At a bare minimum,

```
int temp = arr[right];
arr[right] = arr[left];
arr[left] = arr[temp];
```

will *not* do what you think it will.

You're storing the value (not the index) into `temp` in the first line and then using it as an *index* in the third line. That's not going to end well at all.

Instead, you want to use the value as a *value:*

```
int temp = arr[right];
arr[right] = arr[left];
arr[left] = temp;
```

You have a similar issue in your comparisons between `pivot` (an index) and `arr[right]/arr[left]` (a value).

Those loops setting `left` and `right` are also going to cause grief. You should be *incrementing* `left` since you want to send it toward the end of the array, and *decrementing* `right` for a similar reason.

Comment: Thanks. I corrected that.
However, the error seems to persist.

Answer (score 2):

In your code, `left = 0` in your `quicksort` function. And,

```
while(pivot>arr[left])
        left--;
```

here, in this code, `left` would go to negative value, if the `pivot` value is more then `arr[left]`, i.e. `arr[0]`. This is most probably causing your code to `seg fault`.

I think according to your code, the right version would be

```
while(pivot>arr[left])      //elements < pivot on the left side
    left++;
while (pivot<arr[right])   //elemenst > pivot in the right side
    right--;
```

**Note**

Also understand that i cannot find any **terminating condition** in your recursive call.

You would want your recursion to get over when a certain criteria is met. In this case when `_left >= _right`. This should be checked in the beginning to make sure that that your function doesn't enter infinite recursion.